# JPMS and foreign JAR files often lead to ResolutionException

Tags: java, java-17, java-platform-module-system

This question has been asked here several times. But I did not find a usable answer so far (for years now). As I am doing small Java-17 programs using big jar files, I am wondering whether JPMS is the right way to go. That means whether Java is the right language for small programs.

My **actual problem**:

My JPMS programs work from within Eclipse and m2e. That is fine in most cases. But sometimes I have to distribute my program.

Due to module dependencies on a service provider starting the program from batch, it needs a module-path. This seems to be incompatible with exporting the program from Eclipse as a Runnable JAR File. Hence, I am trying to put all jars in one lib folder and start the main module. But I got an **error**:

```
java -p target/lib -m my-module-package/my-module-package.Main some parameters
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules com.tngtech.junit.dataprovider.junit4 and com.tngtech.junit.dataprovider.core export package com.tngtech.junit.dataprovider.resolver to module commons.logging
```

In my Java-17 program, I am refering to my utility module. That module is tested using JGiven and refers to a dataprovider:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tngtech.jgiven</groupId>
            <artifactId>jgiven-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tngtech.junit.dataprovider</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit4-dataprovider</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
        </dependency>
```

Both module jar files seem to host the package `com.tngtech.junit.dataprovider.resolver` what causes the error.

The only advice I found so for resolving that error is to contact the module owners.

And I expect, when I have solved that one error I will face the next ResolutionException.

Is there any quick general solution? E.g. how to specify to use only the first package found and ignore the others? Or: How to repack the dependent modules jar file without the conflicting package and offer that jar file to Maven?

Comment: Your description is confusing. Are you talking about your program or about someone else’s program?

Comment: Holger, I am talking about "My JPMS program", that is based on several Java modules, that I have not created, e.g. JGiven.

Putting maven-shade-plugin in pom.xml, I got an interesting [install output](https://paste.fo/raw/6336f81bbae0). Seems to list all JPMS problems in the used modules.

Comment: The restriction that a package must belong to a single module without ambiguity, is fundamental. If your modular program works fine with the modules it requires, then all those modules must obey this restriction already. Your reason why you suddenly throw ten thousand jar files into the module path, is incomprehensible. Non-modular software still works as intended when being provided through the classpath. And software with split packages obviously is non-modular.